# How to use an svg image as a font or an icon within the text in a markdown file?

Tags: html, css, svg, markdown

In my markdown file, I wrote html as follows.
Please note that the svg image is used as a font or a small icon but a usual image on the web.

```html
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 10 10' width='10' height='10' fill='#666'>  
    <path d='M0 10 L5 5 L0 0 Z' />
    </svg>Title, hello world 

Some text.
```

I expected that the title line started with the svg image. But it did with some unwanted spaces as follows.

#### $spaces$svg$Title, hello world

Some text.

How can I remove the unwanted spaces?

> As a complement, it is for machine generating markdown pages. So a large size of solution code is affordable for me.

Comment: Can you please [format your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/242137) properly. It looks like you've inadvertently applied the heading style to your expected layout. Also, if you don't want a space between the svg and the word "Title", why is there a space between the closing `</svg>` tag and the word "Title" in your markup?

Comment: @r3mainer,let me correct things you pointed out.

Comment: @r3mainer, oh, I don't say that I don't want a space between the svg and the word "Title". Instead  I don't want spaces leading the svg.

Comment: you remove the space before the svg by reseting the css (margin:0;padding:0). In order to remove the space between the svg and the Title you will need to change the viewBox  of the svg element. Please try adding a background color to the svg element to see that this space is part of the svg elemet